# I'm trying to format the dropdown menu next but it doesn't seem to be letting me

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I am relatively new to coding. I am trying to create a program where you are able to type information into boxes about a book. This info can either be submitted and saved into a txt file, cleared. I want you to also be able to search for books by clicking the search button where you can search for a book by typing in its name. The condition tab is meant to have the dropdown menu in with options but I can't format it. As I am new to code I expect there is plenty of problems with my code but it would be greatly appreciated if I could get some help with this. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
bookshopFile=open("bookshop.txt","a")

root=Tk()
root.geometry("1000x600")
root.title("Book Shop")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(bg="#d9e7fc")
frame_heading=Frame(root)
frame_heading.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2, padx=100,pady=5)
frame_entry=Frame(root)
frame_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2, padx=25,pady=10)

def Submit():
    Book_Title_get=Book_Title.get()
    Author_get=Author.get()
    Genre_get=Genre.get()
    YoP=Year_of_Publication.get()
    Condition_get=Condition.get()

    bookshopFile.write(Book_Title_get+","+Author_get+",
    "+Genre_get+","+YoP+","+Condition_get+"\n")
    bookshopFile.close()

def Clear():
    Book_Title.delete(0,END)
    Author.delete(0,END)
    Genre.delete(0,END)
    Year_of_Publication.delete(0,END)
    Condition.delete(0,END)

def Search():
    Label(frame_entry,text="Name of Book").grid(row=6,column=0, 
    padx=10,pady=0)
    Name_of_Book=Entry(frame_entry,width=20,bg="white")
    Name_of_Book.grid(row=6,column=1, padx=10,pady=0)

Label(frame_heading, text= "Book Shop").grid(row=0,column=0, 
padx=0,pady=0)
Label(frame_entry,text="Book Title").grid(row=1,column=0, 
padx=10,pady=0)
Label(frame_entry,text="Author").grid(row=2,column=0, padx=10,pady=0)
Label(frame_entry,text="Genre").grid(row=3,column=0, padx=10,pady=0)
Label(frame_entry,text="Year of Publication").grid(row=4,column=0, 
padx=10,pady=0)
Label(frame_entry,text="Condition").grid(row=5,column=0, 
padx=10,pady=0)
Book_Title=Entry(frame_entry,width=20,bg="white")
Book_Title.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=10,pady=0)
Author=Entry(frame_entry,width=20,bg="white")
Author.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=10,pady=0)
Genre=Entry(frame_entry,width=20,bg="white")
Genre.grid(row=3,column=1, padx=10,pady=0)
Year_of_Publication=Entry(frame_entry,width=20,bg="white")
Year_of_Publication.grid(row=4,column=1, padx=10,pady=0)

choices = ['Used','New','Other']

tkvar = StringVar(root)
tkvar.set(choices[0])

C_Popup = OptionMenu(root, tkvar, *choices)
C_Popup.grid(row=5, column=1) 

root.mainloop()
Condition=Entry(C_Popup,width=20)
Condition.C_Popup(row=5,column=1)

button1=Button(root,text="Submit",width=7,command=Submit)
button1.grid(row=8,column=0)
button2=Button(root,text="Clear",width=7,command=Clear)
button2.grid(row=9,column=0)
button3=Button(root,text="Search",width=7,command=Search)
button3.grid(row=10,column=0)
```

Comment: You can start by moving root.mainloop() to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the line

`C_Popup = OptionMenu(root, tkvar, *choices)`

to

`C_Popup = OptionMenu(frame_entry, tkvar, *choices)`

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you! do u know how i get the submit, clear, and search buttons to appear under this, they work fine without the dropdown but for some reason they disappear when the dropdown is implemented

Comment: this is because you are calling `root.mainloop()` before you've created and placed the Button elements on your grid layout. to fix this, just move the code where you create and place the Button elements on the grid directly **before** `root.mainloop()`

Comment: Thanks again still getting used to debugging